# Подсчет количества гласных в предложении

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Моя программа должна рассчитать кол-во гласных букв в предложении. Подсчета количества повторов букв смог добиться через ассоциативный массив. Дальше мои знания упираются в тупик..

```
from collections import Counter

a = input()
s = a
bukvi = []
i = []
glasnie = [ 'а' , 'у' , 'о' , 'ы' , 'и' , 'э' , 'я' , 'ю' ,
            'ё' , 'е' ,  ]
lst = s.split()
for item in lst: 
    R = item
    bukvi += R
print(bukvi)
Q = list(set(bukvi) & set(glasnie))
print(Q)
D = [ x for x in bukvi if bukvi.count(x) > 1 ]
print(D)
t = 0

array = D
c = Counter(array)
print(c)
```

Comment: Для чего переменная ``s``, если можно сразу использовать ``a``? То же самое про ``R`` и ``array``. ``t`` вообще не используется.

Comment: Это черновая версия вырванная из более крупной части кода. Не успел еще отформатировать и оптимизировать всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vowels = ['а' , 'у' , 'о' , 'ы' , 'и' , 'э' , 'я' , 'ю' , 'ё' , 'е']

count = sum(1 for c in list(input()) if c.lower() in vowels)
```

Comment: `count = sum(1 for c in input().lower() if c in 'ауоыиэяюёе')`?

Comment: @gil9red да, так даже лучше.

Comment: А можно и так: `count = sum(c in 'ауоыиэяюёе' for c in input().lower())` :)

Answer (score 4):

Решение в функциональном стиле:

```
count = sum(map(lambda c: c in 'ауоыиэяюёе', input().lower()))
print(count)
```

Вариант без лямбды используя `count`:

```
count = sum(map('ауоыиэяюёе'.count, input().lower()))
print(count)
```

Вариант без лямбды используя магический метод оператора `in` (не нужно так делать):

```
count = sum(map('ауоыиэяюёе'.__contains__, input().lower()))
print(count)
```

Comment: `lambda c: c in 'ауоыиэяюёе'` -> `'ауоыиэяюёе'.count`

Comment: А еще можно и `'ауоыиэяюёе'.__contains__` :) Спасибо, добавил

Comment: Можно и так, главное - уйти от создания новой функции там, где уже есть готовый метод объекта.